# Promo Code expiration Doubt

Tags: checkout, promotions

I am facing a situation & not much clear as it is default Magento's way of working or something !

Say I have created a shopping cart rule ( discount Promo Code) which get expire on *25-Dec-2015* and suppose a customer apply the code and abandon the order ( ie added to cart and applied the discount code but placed the order ) . Now the same guy comes after "*25-Dec-2015*" and checkout the order from his cart ( in which Discount code was applied), in this case should not be applied Discount Coupon should expire ??

Comment: Yes, discount coupon won't be applied in that case. Is this still applied in your case ?

Comment: yes discount coupon is not expired for the order that are added to cart when discount code was valid @Prateek